# Converting data from Chaboche material model from ABAQUS to ANSYS

Tags: materials, ansys, abaqus

How to minimize differences when using Chaboche model in ABAQUS and in ANSYS.

For example as I've noticed – in ABAQUS one has rate-dependent plasticity model, but in ANSYS it is rate independent plasticity model. What does it mean? Can we just omit rate-dependent part when inputing values in ANSYS Workbench? What should I account for when using ANSYS?

Answer (score 0):

Rate independent means it does not depend on time. Example of rate dependent would be creep, where constant stress leads to constant strain rate in time ($\dot{\epsilon} = \frac{d\epsilon}{dt} = const$) or viscoplasticity. I think "basic" Chaboche model is rate independent.

Comment: Thank you for answer